# Spring Security - unable to catch LDAP exception when AD server offline

Tags: java, spring-security

I have Spring Security LDAP authentication up and running in our application and everything is running smoothly with it, apart from one aspect. That is
if the AD Server happens to be offline or uncontactable then a org.springframework.ldap.CommunicationException is thrown. However this exception is uncaught 
and propagates back to the client as a Tomcat HTTP 500 error page including the stack trace (shown below).

I'm using java config with Spring Security 4.0.1, Java 8 and Tomcat 7.0.42.

```
springframework.ldap.CommunicationException: localhost:389; nested exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: localhost:389 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]
org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapUtils.convertLdapException(LdapUtils.java:108)
org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.bindAsUser(ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:211)
org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.doAuthentication(ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:143)
org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:82)
org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:167)
org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:192)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:93)
... other frames omitted
```

There's none of our code on this exception trace, even further up the stack (which I've omitted for brevity as it's just the Servlet filter chain).

Normally I this kind of situation I would just subclass the Spring ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider class and in that derived class call
the base class doAuthentication() method inside a try/catch and go from there. Unfortunately ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider is declared 
as final so I can't do this.

I've tried a few other things in an attempt to try and catch that exception in my code. These are

1. Added an authenticationfailurehandler the formLogin configuration as below. But this doesn't get called when the exception gets thrown, it only seems
   to fire for authentication based exceptions,

   ```
       ...
       .formLogin()            
           .usernameParameter("j_username")
           .passwordParameter("j_password")            
           .loginPage("/login.jsp")
           .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")         
           .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler())
           .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler())
       .and()
       ...
   ```
2. Set up an authenticationEndpoint for any non-authenticated requests with the following code in my SecurityConfig.java file,

   ```
       ...
       .formLogin()            
           .usernameParameter("j_username")
           .passwordParameter("j_password")            
           .loginPage("/login.jsp")
           .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")         
           .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler())
       .and()
       .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(myAuthenticationEntryPoint())
       ...
   ```

where the myAuthenticationEntryPoint() method is a @Bean annotated method that just returns a new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint. But again this doesn't get called 
and I still get an HTTP 500 error back rather than a 403 from the configured authentication entry point.

The actual method that throws the exception in the Spring Security source code is shown below:

```
private DirContext bindAsUser(String username, String password) {
    // TODO. add DNS lookup based on domain
    final String bindUrl = url;

    Hashtable<String,String> env = new Hashtable<String,String>();
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    String bindPrincipal = createBindPrincipal(username);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, bindPrincipal);
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, bindUrl);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.OBJECT_FACTORIES, DefaultDirObjectFactory.class.getName());

    try {
        return contextFactory.createContext(env);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        if ((e instanceof AuthenticationException) || (e instanceof OperationNotSupportedException)) {
            handleBindException(bindPrincipal, e);
            throw badCredentials(e);
        } else {
            throw LdapUtils.convertLdapException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

For the case where the AD server is not contactable then the code goes into the else clause in the exception handler and we get an Ldap based exception. As far as I can see this means that none of the 'normal' authentication failure handlers get called.

The only way I found to catch this exception was to 'fork' the ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider class, ie cut + paste it's contents into a new class and derive a class from that. Doing that works as expected and I can catch the exception in a try/catch. But I don't really want to go for this option as it's just a hack.

Has anyone had a similar situation and found a more elegant solution to it? I can't help but think that there must be a way to handle ALL exceptions during
the logon process, not just authentication based ones, but I've been unable to find a way to do this.

Comment: i Had the same problem, so I had to implements my own `AuthenticationProvider`, maybe putting yoru own error page in web.xml will help you:  `<error-page>
  <error-code>500</error-code>
  <location>/error.htm</location>
 </error-page>`

Comment: @DavidHerrero, thanks for the reply. I was hoping that there was just a missing piece in my configuration. Having to implement my own AuthenticationProvider just to catch an exception seems quite heavyweight. Not that I'm doubting what you're saying :), maybe that is the only way.

Comment: I will write an small answer that may help you.

Comment: This is a real problem, since when this exception is thrown, it prevents other authentication providers from being activated in order to try authentication the user with them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just wrote this in @kpentchev answer:

> My expected behaviour when this exception is thrown is that I can
>   catch it and return the user to login page with a suitable error.
>   Rather than the use just seeing the blue Tomcat 500 error page with
>   the exception trace.

If you just want to "block" the default Tomcat Error page so attackers or users can not see important info about your server you can put this in your web.xml:

```
<error-page> 
<error-code>500</error-code> 
<location>/error.jsp</location> 
</error-page>
```

After, in you error.jsp page you can check the Exception with:

```
Throwable throwable = (Throwable) request
                .getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception");
```

And redirect the user to the login page in case throwable is an instance of `CommunicationException.class`

Comment: Yes this does do what I want, in the fact that it sends the user back to the login.jsp page when this error happens. It's a shame that you can't handle this exception in the Spring Security java config and you have to put in a jsp file. However it should be a very rare occurrence and now it is actually handled. So I'm accepting this as the answer, thanks for your help David :)

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `ControllerAdvice` that handles `ldap.CommunicationException`. You can specify the Response or view per exception type.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class LdapErrorController {

    @ExceptionHandler({CommunicationException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorMessage> handleLdapCommunicationException(Exception ex) {
        return new ResponseEntity<ErrorMessage>(new ErrorMessage("Can not connect to LDAP server."), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

}
```

The example will return the ErrorMessage serialized in the response body according to the Accept headers of the Request. If you would like to provide a view, you can directly return a `ModelAndView` or a `RedirectView`.

Comment: thanks for the response. However, this isn't a Spring MVC application. I'm just using Spring Security to secure an Angular JS based application. I'm not sure whether I can just use the ExceptionHandler annotation with a class that I have derived from a Spring Security class. I'll give it go.

Comment: Well since you are using `spring.security.web` you are also using `spring.webmvc`. How you make it work together with angularjs is another question entirely. What is your expected behavior when this exception occurs?

Comment: "Well since you are using spring.security.web you are also using spring.webmvc", I don't think that's actually true. I don't have the spring-webmvc artifact in my pom file. Like I mentioned the application is working fine apart from this one issue. My expected behaviour when this exception is thrown is that I can catch it and return the user to login page with a suitable error. Rather than the use just seeing the blue Tomcat 500 error page with the exception trace.

Comment: True, spring.webmvc is an optional dependency of spring.security.web. The latter however does depend on spring.web, which contains the `ControllerAdvice` annotation class.