# How to handle misconfigured/rogue ActiveDirectory Server in Spring Security 4.1+?

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, active-directory

The environment in which my app will live is...strange.

My Spring Boot 1.4/Spring Security 4.1+ application is able to successfully connect using LDAPS: to Active Directory using Spring Security's ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider via Java Configuration.

Most of the time.

In my corporate environment there exist 12 Active Directory instances accessible through a round-robin DNS entry. Investigation shows me that 2 of these are badly configured; they have different/wrong certificates to the other 10.

This means that when I try to handshake with the server, 1/6 of the time I get a ConnectException (caused by SSL handshake error) and my app bounces to its "something bad has happened" handler/UI page. Not good for the users. Next login attempt from the same server goes to a different server in the round-robin list and is usually successful (unless it finds the other 'bad' server).

There is NO WAY I will be able to convince The Powers That Be to modify the AD servers for my irrelevant little app so I need to work around this issue.

I am darned if I can find a way of retrying a failed authentication attempt.

Tomorrow (now at home) I will try supplying multiple URLs to ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider's constructor since the source javadoc notes:

> - @param url an LDAP url (or multiple URLs)

I'll report back on if this works...

I can also try adding a @Exception handler, as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/32822853/3631003 but that's not really what I want...I don't want to ask the user to manually retry the login process.

I'm also not too keen on the idea of forking ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider as described at [Spring Security - unable to catch LDAP exception when AD server offline](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32818144/3631003)...

This feels like it is a FAQ but my google-fu is obviously lacking because I haven't found anything.

Any other suggestions/experiences as to how I can use spring security to work around this vexatious and frankly ridiculous situation would be gratefully received.

Comment: This is a more generally relevant question as well: what to do if a server fails and one wants to changeover to a backup server? In that case, getting a timeout from S1 and trying S2 is soemthng that one would want to do...

Comment: I have tried the multiple URL approach. SEEMS to work. I will continue testing and report back.